# CSS background is not visible in mac osx browsers but visible in windows browsers

Tags: html, css

I have a html page, in which i have given background using CSS background-image property

I am able to view background in all major browsers(Firefox, IE, Chrome,Safari) of windows but when i run same page in MAc osx browser(safari or chrome), background is not visible, rest all CSS is working good

My CSS is

```
 border-top: 5px solid #00bdb3;
 margin: 10px 0 0 0 ;
 background-image:url('/Images/back.jpg');
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
```

where is the problem, i am not able to find

i have tried to give inline styling also but results were same, i was still not able to see background in Mac Browsers

Comment: Try validating your CSS: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ Failing that, try to replicate the issue with a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing the CSS:

```
background-image:url('/Images/back.jpg');
```

to:

```
background-image:url('../Images/back.jpg');
```

Answer (score -1):

Just try to validate your CSS, just like @Chris Hardie.

If it doesn't meet your need, please [read this solution](http://tuljo.com/web-development/css-mac-safari-background-problem).